# Easy way to convert the month name into month number in php

Tags: php

I want to enter the full name of the month and in response i want to get the number of the month.
i have tried following code, when i pass the "March" as month name it return me "1".is there any way to get the number of the month in php?

```
$month_number = date('n', strtotime($string));
```

Comment: That code returns "1" for January or _any unrecognised string_ that's passed into `strtotime`. It successfully returns "3" if I pass "March" as `$string` to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
  $date = date_parse('March');
  echo($date['month']);
?>
```

May this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
date('m', strtotime("March"));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.